# SELECT AS in PHP and Android (JSON) causes error

Tags: php, mysql

Everytime I add AS to my SELECT-Query Android Logcat throws an error. I have two columns with the same name and i would like to rename them.

```
    SELECT test1 AS test-1, test2 AS test-2, ... and so on.
```

Without AS I get a result, with AS i throws the following error:

E/JSON Parser(14890): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of.

Could someone explain how to use AS in Select-Statement?

**EDIT :**

```
    SELECT ship.name, ship.size, ship.country AS coun_1, man.country AS coun_2
    FROM shipp ship JOIN manuf man ON ship.id = man.id;
```

Country has the same name...

Comment: AS is just an allias, try to use underscore(_) instead of hyphen (-)

Comment: test-1 is just an example, i use underscores. i doesn´t work anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please show us the full query as its hard to tell without the actual query..